# Conditional Rendering Redux and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `Component` with an `onClick` event. This event sets in my `global state` some `boolean` to `true`. How can, depending on this `boolean` render/hide another `component`?

I could write something like (pseudocode!)

```
<ParentCompononet

    conditionalRendering(props) {
        if(props.boolean) {
            <ConditionalComponent />
        } else {
            null
        }

     render () {
         return (
             { conditionalRendering }
         )
/>
```

Not sure if that would be the right way

Comment: Probably *too* broad as you currently have it :)  Are you able to `connect` the state variable to the `props` of the component?

Comment: @DavinTryon I think so, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you `connect` the boolean value to props, you could just do something like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {

   return { props.myBool && <MyChildComponent /> };

}
```

or slightly more verbose:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {

   if (props.myBool) {
       return <MyChildComponent />;
   } else {
       return null;
   }    
}
```

Comment: I edited my Q. Nearly what I wrote in pseudocode I think?

Comment: Yeah, looks about the same :)

Comment: Awesome. Wasnt sure if that is the proper way/best practice to do it!

Comment: Does it matter that the state object is an object For example what if instead of props.myBool I had props.obj.myBool and obj was connect to the state?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have configured react-redux propely, This might be the one you are looking for.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as Actions from '../../actions';



class User extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

    }

    click=()=>{
    this.props.actions.someEvent();
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <div>
        (this.props.useravailable) ? <div>Hello world!</div> : <div/>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

Login.PropTypes = {
  useravailable: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

let mapStateToProps = (state,props) => {
  return {
    useravailable: state.user
  }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions:bindActionCreators(Actions,dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(User);
```