# how can I stop re-rendering with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
 const { uploadImageDataFromServer, showImage, uploadImageDataFromBackground, ShowImageBackground, LoaderRedux, checkUrlExitsBg, checkUrlExitsProfile, UserInformationLoad, UnreadMessageNotification } = useSelector((state) => {
        return {
            showImage: state.ShowImage.value,
            uploadImageDataFromBackground: state.uploadImageDataFromBackground,
            ShowImageBackground: state.ShowImageBackground.value,
            LoaderRedux: state.LoaderRedux,
            checkUrlExitsBg: state.checkUrlExitsBg,
            checkUrlExitsProfile: state.checkUrlExitsProfile,
            UserInformationLoad: state.UserInformationLoad.value,
            UnreadMessageNotification: state.UnreadMessageNotification,
            uploadImageDataFromServer: state.uploadImageDataFrom,
        }
    })
```

This is inside the functional component called Admin. Problem is that, when Admin component once render. then if any state change inside redux. again Admin component re-render. How can i stop this.
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Do you mean to say that, if any other state other than the one you are interested in updates then the Admin components get re render?

Comment: you know that if any state change in redux store then all state automatically update, when  it is update. then Admin component also re-render on state updation. but I want only admin component  render at once either redux state change or not.

Comment: you may store the redux data to local state and cooperate with useEffect to implement your requirements. is the redux data bind to any ui element?

Comment: maybe you can call redux selectors in parent component of Admin and then pass these data as props to Admin component. and then call `useEffect(()=>{},[])` in Admin component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179327/conditional-rendering-redux-and-react

Comment: thanks, for your reply, I will do this.